# Compilation of Examples of Irreducible Polynomials in Two Variables

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I'm toying around with curves, in particular singular curves, but I don't have a lot of examples to look at.  Is there somewhere where I can find a nice list of examples?  I would be particularly interested in examples of irreducible cubic polynomials in $\overline{k}[X,Y]$, but where the coefficients lie in a nonperfect field $k$.

Comment: I don't know for arbitrary field, but for $k = \mathbb C$, pick $\tau \in \mathbb H := \{z \in \mathbb C : Im(z) > 0\}$ and look at the torus $X = \mathbb C/\Lambda$ where $\Lambda = \mathbb Z \oplus \tau \mathbb Z$. The equation of your cubic will be $y^2 = x^3 + g_2x + g_3$ where $g_2,g_3$ are some constants depending only on $\Lambda$. Every cubic curve can be obtained this way since you have the law group of the cubic and any abelian group is diffeomorphic to a torus. A plane curve which is diffeomorphic to the torus has genus $1$ so it's a cubic. I don't know for other field.

Comment: Assuming characteristic $p$ you probably want to have curves of the form
$$Y^p-Y=f(X),$$ where $f$ is a polynomial in $X$, in your set of examples. They are Galois extension over $\bar{k}(X)$ unless $f(X)$ is chosen so carelessly that it factors. Those have wild ramification at infinity over $\bar{k}[X]$. Using Witt vectors one can get examples with larger abelian $p$-torsion. I recall having fun calculating at the higher ramification groups of those. Caveat: I don't know how a non-perfect changes this scenery.